# Add Input Placeholder and assign value from input label

Tags: jquery, forms, input, field

I have a form I have to work with - I cannot access the HTML. All I can do is apply JS/Jquery and CSS.

My issue:
I need to make the form inputs have placeholder behavior across all browsers.
The caveat - I will need to add the placeholder attribute, and then assign a value from the same input's label attribute. (The form also has no  fields above inputs, and is doing something silly with DIVs

Here is the HTML I have to work with:

```
<input label="First Name" class="textInput defaultText" type="text">
```

As noted - JS/Jquery are okay, as is CSS. Looking for the best way to do this with even IE in mind.

Thanks ahead everyone!

Answer (score 0):

> will need to add the placeholder attribute, and then assign a value
>   from the same input's label attribute.

Try utilizing [`.attr( attributeName, function )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) , setting `placeholder` , `value` ; returning original value for `label` attribute

```js
// call `.attr()` with `label` as parameter 
$(".textInput").attr("label", function(i, attr) {
   // set `placeholder` to `label`:`attr` ,
   // set `value` to `label`
   $(this).attr({
     "placeholder": attr,
     "value": attr
   });
   // return `label` original value
   return attr
});

console.log($(".textInput")[0].attributes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input label="First Name" class="textInput defaultText" type="text">
```

Comment: This is great!
But, remember that my forms several <input> do not have the placeholder attribute as-is. I will need to use JS to add a 'placeholder=""' value to 'fill' with the parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: @user3850554 Yes. `.textInput` `class` utilized as selector to include all `.textInput` elements .  `placeholder` attribute is added at `$(this).attr({
     "placeholder": attr,
     "value": attr
   });` , set to `label` value within `.attr("label", fn);` see set `attributes` of `.textInput`  at `console` .

Comment: ^awesome thanks!
I removed the "value": attr as I do not want loaded values to pass if the form is submitted.
I then used conditional IE statements to display regular labels - as this is not working in <IE9